# WordPress, вопрос касательно permalink settings

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на WordPress + WooCommerce.

Сейчас адрес интересующей меня страницы в следующем формате:

https://www.creativewalls.co.il/product-category/shop/

Мне нужно убрать "product category base" чтобы получилось:

https://www.creativewalls.co.il/shop/

Я перепробовал несколько способов в том числе вот этот [How to remove product-category slug in WooCommerce](https://www.tutorialswebsite.com/how-to-remove-product-category-slug-in-woocommerce/)

После него у меня перестала работать корзина. Возвращает код 404.

Посоветуйте пожалуйста оптимальное решение, либо может какой бесплатный плагин.

Вот permalink settings

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых у тебя какой-то бред - почему `shop` после `product-category`? ЧПУ покажи. Во-вторых см https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/woocommerce-kill-performance/

Comment: Добавил скрин с permalink settings. Контентер создал там единственную категорию со слагом shop по какой то причине. Статью прочитал, согласен с ней. Да, это требования сеошника.

Comment: На скрине всё верно - `product-category/shop`, а не то что ты написал в тексте. А сеошника лишать зарплаты и гнать в шею.

Comment: У тебя "сайт/shop/" и работает. А вот "сайт/product-category/shop" отдаёт 200, а должен 404. Вот тут ты накосячил.

Comment: У меня есть единственная категория. У нее слаг shop, вот почему она отдает 200

Comment: "shop" не должна быть категорий. Это страница магазина. (вот у тебя и первый конфликт) Делай вменяемые категории.

Comment: Да, так и сделаю. Спасибо.